# How to assign a variable to a callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

I've got this function that takes a URL & Callback in:

```
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { return callback(this.width, this.height); }
}
```

And this callback function is called like this: (This works and alerts the correct output e.x. 100px , 100px)

```
    getMeta(
        i_url, //This being the URL (in base64 or real web url)
        function(width, height) { alert(width + 'px ' + height + 'px') }
      );
```

However whenever I try and assign a variable to it, and switch out the alert for return, I get undefined..

```
    const test = getMeta(
        i_url,
        function(width, height) { return width + 'px ' + height + 'px' }
      );
    alert(test);
```

alert's message: undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any value inside the `getMeta` method, you only return from the callback which is never passed out of the original call to `getMeta` method.

Follow this code and see if you understand

```
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    /*
        This return is only assigned to img.onload
        But this assignment does not make any sense. 
    */
    // img.onload = function() { return callback(this.width, this.height); }
    /* if you want to use the image height and width inside your own logic you can include that logic in the callback */
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height) }
    // maybe you can return the IMG from this method
    return img;
}
```

You can declare a global object and reference the width and height from within the callback

```
let imageMeta = {height: null, width: null}
getMeta(
    i_url,
    function(width, height) { imageMeta.width = width; imageMeta.height = height }
);
```

If you want a more robust solution you should look into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)